# How to fadeout header in list view like whatsapp

Tags: android, listview, sticky

[image]i want to fadeout a first visible header in a stickyheaderlistview (lib) . how do i fadeout the first visible header in a list view. please give me some example. thank you. if you observe the date header it will hide if there is no user interaction after some time

Comment: What you have try till ?

Comment: https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Comment: finally did by setAreHeadersSticky to  false in scroll idle state.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile this:

```
compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.1.3'
```

In your adapter

```
public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements StickyListHeadersAdapter {

    private Activity mActivity;
    private SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    private SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    private SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    private SimpleDateFormat headerdateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
    private Date date = null;
    private String msgDate = "";
    private Date headerDate = null;
    private String msgHeader = "";
    private String msg = "";
    private String mName = "";
    private int day = 0;
List<GroupChatHistoryData> mChatArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ChatAdapter(Activity mActivity,List<GroupChatHistoryData> mChatArrayList) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
this.mChatArrayList = mChatArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mChatArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mChatArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_details_row_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.receive_message_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.receive_message_text);
            holder.receive_message_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.receive_message_date);
            holder.receive_member_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.receive_member_name);
            holder.sent_message_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sent_message_date);
            holder.sent_message_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sent_message_text);

            holder.chat_receive_layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_receive_layout);
            holder.sent_msg_ll = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sent_msg_ll);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final GroupChatHistoryData bean = mChatArrayList.get(position);

        try {
            if (bean.getTime() != null && !bean.getTime().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                date = format.parse(bean.getTime());
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (date != null) {
            msgDate = dateformat.format(date);
        }

        msg = bean.getMessage();


// your rest views

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final HeaderViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_header, parent, false);
            holder = new HeaderViewHolder();

            holder.headerDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_date);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (HeaderViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        GroupChatHistoryData bean = mChatArrayList.get(position);

        try {
            if (bean.getDatetime() != null && !bean.getDatetime().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                headerDate = format1.parse(bean.getDatetime());
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (headerDate != null) {
            msgHeader = headerdateformat.format(headerDate);
        }

        if (show(msgHeader) == 0) {
            holder.headerDate.setText("TODAY");
        } else if (show(msgHeader) == -1) {
            holder.headerDate.setText("YESTERDAY");
        } else {
            holder.headerDate.setText(msgHeader);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private class HeaderViewHolder {
        private TextView headerDate;
    }

    @Override
    public long getHeaderId(int position) {
        String mDate = mChatArrayList.get(position).getDatetime();
        int mDatePos = Integer.parseInt(mDate);
        return mDatePos;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView receive_message_text;
        TextView receive_message_date;
        TextView receive_member_name;
        TextView sent_message_date;
        TextView sent_message_text;

        LinearLayout chat_receive_layout;
        LinearLayout sent_msg_ll;
    }

    private int show(String time) {
        try {
            String outputPattern = "dd MMMM yyyy";
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);

            Date Date1 = format.parse(getdate());
            Date Date2 = format.parse(time);
            long mills = Date2.getTime() - Date1.getTime();
            long Day1 = mills / (1000 * 60 * 60);

            day = (int) Day1 / 24;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return day;
    }


    private String getdate() {
        String time = "";
        try {
            String outputPattern = "dd MMMM yyyy";

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);
            time = df.format(c.getTime());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return time;
    }

}
```

chat_header.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#BDD9E4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

GroupChatHistoryData Bean something like this:

```
public class GroupChatHistoryData {


    private SimpleDateFormat headerdateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    private Date headerDate = null;
    private Date mTime = null;
    private SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    private SimpleDateFormat timeformat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private String userId;
    @SerializedName("group_id")
    @Expose
    private String groupId;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("datetime")
    @Expose
    private String datetime;
    @SerializedName("fname")
    @Expose
    private String fname;
    @SerializedName("time")
    @Expose
    private String time;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getDatetime() {

        String date = "";
        try {
            if (datetime != null && !datetime.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                headerDate = format.parse(datetime);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (headerDate != null) {
            date = headerdateformat.format(headerDate);
        }

        return date;
    }

    public void setDatetime(String datetime) {
        this.datetime = datetime;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }


    public boolean isMine() {
        return isMine;
    }

    public void setMine(boolean mine) {
        isMine = mine;
    }

    public boolean isMine = false;

    public String getTime() {

        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Maroof , i am able to show the sticky headers but my issue is to toggle header visibility when user scrolls and stops the scroll like whatsapp. thank u

Comment: Yes, the code which I shared here is doing the same as per your req (same as whatsapp). Did you try my code?

Comment: This library is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try ObservableScrollView.

https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: But I can't this post to comment so

Comment: No problem. Cheers !

Comment: I think i did not conveyed properly ,sorry i  am very poor iin english.Actually my issue is, in whats app if user did not scroll the list view then the header will be hidden and if user scrolls it will display again . i need such implementation. Thank you @KingofMasses

Comment: You can use simple parallax scrollview(ObservableScrollview) no need to use listview or recyclerview and ObservableScrollview you can manage hide or show header easy :)